# Why wouldn't a C++ compiler implement <cstdint>?

Tags: c++

I am porting some C++ code to [SHArC](https://www.analog.com/en/product-category/sharc-audio-processors-socs.html) processor, and I noticed the SHArC C++ compiler doesn't implement <[cstdint](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdint)>.

What's the reason for this, and how do I port numerous `#include <cstdint>` from the original code?

Comment: Try just replacing `#include <cstdint>` with `#include <stdint.h>` and see what happens.  Many C++ programmers use the former improperly anyway.

Comment: @BenVoigt I'm curious about the alluded-to improper uses.

Comment: What compiler do you use? Is it conforming C++11?

Comment: @sweenish: If code uses `int32_t` and friends, unqualified, it depends on `<stdint.h>`.  But many programmers will erroneously include `<cstdint>` instead because "<stdint.h> is a C header and this is C++ code".  Well, `<cstdint>` is only guaranteed to provide those names inside the `std` namespace.  So the code must also be updated to use `std::int32_t`, either by adding qualifiers to the name everywhere, or by `using std::int32_t`.

Comment: It's Analog's SHArC compiler, there is a `-c++11` switch which supports 2011 features, but not all.

Comment: Reading those [specs](https://www.analog.com/en/products/adsp-sc570.html) *"These 32-bit/40-bit/64-bit floating-point processors are optimized for high performance audio/floating-point applications"* makes me wonder if they *could* have any of the types in `<cstdint>`.

Comment: @BenVoigt For some reason I had it in my head that `<cstdint>` had both versions defined. Good to know.

Comment: @sweenish: Several popular toolchains do define both versions, because the Standard leaves it unspecified.  So then the code which includes `<cstdint>` and fails to qualify the names appears to work but is not portable to other Standard-conformant C++ compilers.

Comment: @BenVoigt I tried replacing `#include <cstdint>` with `#include <stdint.h>`, but now I get errors like: `namespace "std" has no member "int64_t"`, etc... Is replacement really the way to go?

Comment: @Danijel: It looks like you have code that actually knew how to use `<cstdint>` properly and didn't just use it as an "upgrade" of `<stdint.h>`.  It was worth a try.  If you want to continue down that path, change `std::int64_t` to `::int64_t` (mutatis mutandi for the other stdint types).  Could be a lot of work, and will make it hard to integrate future changes from upstream.

Comment: Alternatively, you could write your own `cstdint` file, which would basically be `#include <stdint.h> namespace std { typedef ::uint64_t uint64_t; /* similar for other stdint types */ }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing tricky about `<cstdint>`, a valid version is as follows:

```
#pragma once /* or include-guard macro */
#include <stdint.h>

namespace std
{
    typedef ::uint64_t uint64_t;
    typedef ::uint64_fast_t uint64_fast_t;
    typedef ::uint64_least_t uint64_least_t;

    typedef ::int64_t int64_t;

    /* similar for other stdint types */
}
```

Comment: You can `using ::uint64_t;` and save some typing.